# Play 2.6 using Logging Markers to carry request uuid similar to Java MDC

Tags: scala, playframework, logback, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to use Logging Markers to carry contextual information during the whole cycle of a request. Basically, I want to assign a `uuid` to a request and after that, all logging related to that HTTP request, should print that request `uuid`.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaLogging#using-markers-and-marker-contexts

I see the example with logstash, but I don't use logstash.

I know it can be done with the MDC. Can/How can it be done with Logging Markers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what your logging configuration looks like. The examples from your link use the marker to annotate each log entry. If you go to the next link, [SettingsLogger](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger), you will see how to configure logback to print out your logs to a file. You will need to modify the layout encoder to add "%marker" to the pattern layout. For instance,

```
 "%-5level (%marker)[%thread]: %message%n"
```

will print out your log item with the UUID just before the thread name.

Comment: What I don't understand is that the Marker seems to be a constant String in the code but I want a dynamic uuid (different on each request) in the logs. I know this may sound dumb but how do I assign the `%marker` in your example, a dynamic uuid ?

Comment: You call the marker factory method with the string you want to make in to a marker. The Marker class is a wrapper for a string, which is often part of a hierarchy. So, generate your UUID string, get the factory to create a marker for you, and then use that marker in your logging statements.

Comment: `val uuid: String = genUUID();  val m2 = MarkerFactory.getMarker("marker");  logger.info("stuff")(m2) ` Ok, so I generate the uuid. I get the "marker" marker using the factory and use that marker in the logging. The `uuid` is still not connected to anything. I understand I should not be calling `getMarker(uuid)`.

Comment: `val uuid: String = genUUID(); val m2 = MarkerFactory.getMarker(uuid); logger.info("stuff")(m2);` You need to create the marker with the *value* of the UUID.

Comment: Arrgh true... It's working. Thanks for your patience!